# Could this circular data reference be designed better?

Tags: database-design

I have data about colors.
Some of those colors consist of a number of colors combined.
One of those combinations can theoretically be another combined color.
In the case of a combined color, I need to define a few attributes about the "child" colors.

I currently have my database defined like so:

```
COLOR
 !Id
 +MultiColorGroupId

MULTICOLOR
  !Id
  +MultiColorGroupId
  +ColorId
  +Type
```

This can contain all the information I need in a pretty clear way.
The only thing I'm thinking that could happen is that I get a circular reference where a color has itself as childColor.
Currently the only way to catch this is by building a check on insert in either the database or the application. As the circle reference could be arbitrarely deep, and the current structure can potentially be rather wide i would prefer a more deterministic data structure.

Are there better ways to define this?

Comment: Obvious answer - build the check into the database. Perhaps extend the question to explain why this is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the depth can be arbitrary then you cannot solve the problem in the data structure. One thing to consider is if it is a problem if the self-reference is in fact stored in the database. Perhaps it should be up to the retrieving code to ensure it doesn't read the data infinitely.

I had a similar problem with food recipes. It takes yogurt to make yogurt (to pick a common example), so we had to support storing that, and put logic on the retrieval to ensure that a given ingredient is only exploded once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interface (other than SQL) to these tables, you could easily exclude all "illegal" options from the available selections. Otherwise on-insert and on-update triggers or check constraints could be used.

Comment: The problem is that the circle could be arbitrarly deep, so this could become an expensive operation to check every time. But on insert triggers are the best thing I've seen so far :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do this in code, although I would caution against triggers - as you point out the cost of the triggers are going to be a lot worse than a linear relation depending on how complex your structures are.

In code with a collection it is a very simple problem to solve.

Really your table definitions cannot define this scenario out, it is a rule that is a property of the data itself, not the storing structure.

As for the data structure, I came up with the same structure.