# How do I define table relations in a circular reference?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

In my current project I have data about colors.
Each color is either a real color (with RGB values) or is a "container color" that exist out of multiple layers of colors.
This potentially creates circular references which will have to be caught at application level (but that's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079548/could-this-circular-data-reference-be-designed-better))

So I have

```
Colors
------
+ (PK) Id

ColorComposition
-----------
+ (PK) Id
+ (FK) MotherColorId
+ (FK) ChildColorId
```

When I add them to my Linq2Sql schema I get weird relations. This makes me doubt my structure.

A color should have 0 to many ColorCompositions (Color.Id => ColorComposition.MotherColorId)
A ColorComposition should have many to 1 color (ColorComposition.ChildColorId => Color.Id)

The first relation is interpreted correctly, but the second one isn't. It's in the wrong direction.
How should I define the last relation in terms of foreign keys?

Comment: I didn't understand yet. Is MultiColor a combination of only two colors, or you're trying to represent n colors like a "linked list" (the child from one is a mother in another one)?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079548/could-this-circular-data-reference-be-designed-better by same user

Comment: Please re-read both questions. They do refer to the same situation, but they address a different problem.

Comment: I clarified OP a bit. Hope that makes it more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to store an acyclic directed graph. Try googling 'sql acyclic directed graph'. Here's the top result:

[A Model to Represent Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG) on SQL Databases](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Modeling_DAGs_on_SQL_DBs.aspx)

Your 'MultiColor' table has a confusing name. Consider changing it to 'ColorComposition'?

Comment: You beat me to it. I'd use a different name than MultiColor though, it's somewhat confusing. How about CompositeColor?

Comment: It's basically the name the business gave this system, so I think I'm going to keep the name for that sake.

Comment: Well, it was an interesting read and indeed my problem falls in this category. Although it is much simpler then the situations documented. I think I can find my way from here, thanks.

Comment: Updated the OP to the less confusing ColorComposition label.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column name like Status and put the Mother and Child in this column.
use only one fkColourid in Multicolor table as per id update the status in this status column after your relaitonship work fine.

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you suggest to concat the two id's in one collumn?

Comment: No define one column inplace of two seprate columns and add another column status on this column you able to know that fkcolurid is for child  or parent.